# Advice with sending a reference to another method in the same class

Tags: java, arrays

I am working on a program for class and I am stuck. When I try to compile the following code I receive and variable not found error. please help!

```
public class RingBuffer 
{
    public RingBuffer(int capacity){
        double[] EmptyBuffer = new double[capacity];
        System.out.print(EmptyBuffer.length);

    }

    public int size(){
        int size = EmptyBuffer.length;
        return size;
    }
```

please note that I am getting an error with the size() method not being able to find the variable EmptyBuffer.

Comment: `EmptyBuffer` is a local variable to your constructor. Once the constructor finish it goes out of scope (it no longer exists).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should probably make that a field, aka an instance variable:

```
public class RingBuffer 
{
    private double[] emptyBuffer;

    public RingBuffer(int capacity){
        emptyBuffer = new double[capacity];
        System.out.print(EmptyBuffer.length);
    }

    public int size(){
        int size = emptyBuffer.length;
        return size;
    }
}
```

This will make `emptyBuffer` available throughout your class, i.e. in any other method.

Comment: by marking `emptyBuffer` in the class declaration as `static`, the problem can be secured better I guess.

Comment: @Mario De Schaepmeester the code compiles fine with variable as a `static` , I will be glad if you can explain a bit about what will be the problem.

Comment: @SushimMukulDutta You **cannot** assign a `static` (class) variable in a constructor. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5093744/1313143). Maybe you meant `final`?

Answer (score 0):

Pass the array as an argument to your `size()` method like you've done with `capacity`:

```
int size(double[] EmptyBuffer){
    int size = EmptyBuffer.length;
    return size;
}
```

Then:

```
double[] EmptyBuffer = new Double[capacity];
int size = size(EmptyBuffer); // make call to size passing the array
                              // as an argument
System.out.print(size);
```

Comment: `int size EmptyBuffer(double[] EmptyBuffer)` wtf?

Comment: Good catch, mis-typed. My mistake.

Comment: Cleared my downvote but still I think your solution makes the fact that he made a class rather obsolete :) it's still a possibility of course.