# initializing a final field

Tags: java, final

This Q rather for verification:

A static final field can be initialized when it's declared:

```
public static final int i=87;
```

or in the static block:

```
public static final int i;

//..........

static {
    ...
    i=87;
    ...

}
```

Is there anywhere, other than the static block, a static final field

```
public static final int i;
```

can be initialized?

Thanks in advance.

Note: saw [Initialize a static final field in the constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5093744/initialize-a-static-final-field-in-the-constructor?rq=1). it's not specific that the static block is the only place to initialized it outside the declaration.

//==============

ADD:

extending @noone's fine answer, in response to @Saposhiente's below:

mixing in some non-static context:

```
public class FinalTest {

private static final int INT = new FinalTest().test();

private int test() {
    return 5;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be "initialized" in any random static method, but only indirectly by using the `static` block, or the variable initialization.

```
public class FinalTest {

    private static final int INT = test();

    private static int test() {
        return 5;
    }
}
```

Or like this:

```
public class FinalTest {

    private static final int INT;

    static {
        INT = test();
    }

    private static int test() {
        return 5;
    }
}
```

Technically, it is not really an initialization in `test()`, but it acts like one.

Answer (score 3):

The [Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.3.1.2) states

> It is a compile-time error if a blank final (§4.12.4) class variable
>   is not definitely assigned (§16.8) by a static initializer (§8.7) of
>   the class in which it is declared.

So the answer to

> Is there anywhere, other than the static block, a static final field
>   can be initialized?

No, there isn't.

Answer (score 1):

No. A field that is `static` belongs to the class, and a field that is `final` must be assigned by the time it becomes visible, so a `static final` field must be initialized either with the declaration or in a static initializer (which both get compiled to the same thing) so that it has a value when the class is finished loading.

Answer (score 0):

It can only be initialized in a set of static code that is always run exactly once. This is usually in its declaration or in a static block, but you could also do something weird like

```
static final int i;
static int j = i = 1;
```

which is technically neither of those. Either way, you can't initialize it in any sort of function or constructor because that function might be run more than once; you have to use a static declaration or block of code to run the function and use the return value to initialize it.